# What do the different colors on the map in Pokemon Go represent?

Tags: pokemon-go

I was playing Pokemon Go and the map around me has a blue and green 
color scheme. Does this mean anything or is it just for cosmetic purposes?

Comment: A picture of it would help.

Comment: Do you perhaps mean the grey pixels that take over the map, when you stand on the spot? Or are you referring to the different colours of the map, to begin with?

Comment: Im talking about the different colors to begin with. There is Green near me but in the distance there is blue. Is that just a thing or does it symbolize that I can catch certain pokemon at the different colors?

Answer (score 9):

The different colours you see are different "environments". To quote [the Pokemon GO FAQ](https://support.pokemongo.nianticlabs.com/hc/en-usarticles/221957648-Finding-and-Catching-wild-Pok%C3%A9mon):

> Some wild Pokémon appear only in certain environments and climates. For example, some Pokémon may appear only near lakes, oceans, or other bodies of water

[image: Different environments in Pokemon Go]

"Environments" are based off GPS maps, and are *somewhat* accurate to the real world. You should expect to see water where there should be a lake, and grass where there should be grass. Buildings appear to always show up as grass. Also consider that it will not be 100% accurate; in the screenshot, above, the 'water' is actually a children's playground.

As a side note, if you stay in the same area for a while, the ground appears to slowly turn grey and patchy. From my observations, these are 'dry areas'. They show up if you are in the area for a long time, and Pokemon generally do not spawn when you are standing on them.

Answer (score 0):

Those are colors of terrain. Your environment affects the type of Pokemon you are likely to find.

Answer (score 0):

That blue in the picture is not water, the water shows up much more bright, that dull blue seems to show up in the areas that are green on google maps, which are public parks

Answer (score -1):

If you are referring to the blue and green map from a Intel map. It is the previous game niantic released called ingress. That Map shows the playing field of ingress as to who owns the portals, links, and fields. The Intel map is just used to show some pokestops but not all of ingress portals are pokestops but most are. I know because I played ingress for three years. It's really what started pokemon go. Source - ingress agent level 16! Go enlightened.